# Why does this throw "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.hello."?

Tags: javascript, server, graphql, backend, graphql-js

I had a GraphQL server that I swear worked just a few weeks ago, but now, it's suddenly throwing "cannot null non-nullable field" errors.

Yes, I have checked for duplicates. Yes, I have googled it. Yes, I have checked for related GitHub issues.

I created a minimal repro here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/graphql-drkgtc?file=index.js. Either I'm tired, or there's some breaking change in a minor package version somewhere that I missed.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this object for `root` variable:

```js
var root = {
  Query: {
    hello:() => {return {hello :'hello'}}
  }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me...

Comment: I have tried either your solution and mine , both of them worked correctly with this query`query{ hello { hello } }` . There is no problem with this implementation , go on and check other parts of your code.

Comment: Okay, weird. Probably just a bug in WebContainers. They are experimental, after all.